# Check if repeating event is due on current date

Tags: javascript, logic

Let's assume I have recurring events that meet the following structure:

```
{
    title: "Brunch every saturday morning",
    timestamp: 1569050100 //equals Sat, 21 Sep 2019 09:15:00 in my timezone,
    frequency: "weekly"
}
```

How can I mathematically determine whether this date is due today (or next saturday)?
My approach is the following:

```
eventDate = Determine timestamp of date of recurring event without time
currDate = Determine timestamp of date without time

diff = currDate - eventDate
repetitionFrequency = 604800 //one week in seconds

if (diff mod repetitionFrequency == 0) {
    //On the same day
}
```

Is that efficient? Can you come up with a better way?

Comment: Do you want to only execute the code on the exact second that this event occurs

Comment: No, I want to integrate this code into a function and call it whenever I like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this should help you.

In pseudocode:

```
if ( ( currentSystemTime - 86400) >= (eventSystemTime - eventSystemTime mod 86400) ) {
// we are on the day after the event or later, so move the event forward to next week
eventSystemTime += repetitionFrequency
}
else if (currentSystemTime >= (eventSystemTime - eventSystemTime mod 86400) ) {
// we are on the same day as the event... do event stuff
}
```

EDIT: this code would tell you whether or not you are on the same day, if you want to work out **when** the event will take place otherwise, then you would use the diff variable like so:

```
diff = (eventSystemTime - eventSystemTime mod 86400) - (currentSystemTime - currentSystemTime mod 86400)
diff = diff/86400

// this will produce the difference between now and the event in days
```

Obviously this will be a lot neater programming wise if your eventSystemTime and currentSystemTime were already set to days instead of seconds.

EDIT2: 'mod' in that equation there is the modulo operator, it's just a way of making the eventSystemTime set to midnight on the day of the event